# Why ' i ' don't increase in the for loop?

Tags: react-native

My data in the imageUrl  array . i don't load it with for loop .

```
loadImage() {
    console.log('before', this.state.imagesUrl);

    if (this.state.imagesUrl !== undefined && this.state.imagesUrl.length !== 0) {

        console.log('after', this.state.imagesUrl);
        const  n = this.state.imagesUrl.length;
        console.log('length' , n);
        for ( let  i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
            // i = i + 1
            console.log('element', i, this.state.imagesUrl[i]);
            return (
                    <Image
                    source={{ uri: this.state.imagesUrl[i] }}
                    style={{ width: 45, height: 45, marginLeft: 2, marginTop: 2, marginRight: 2, borderRadius: 10 }}
                    />
            )


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That 'return' statement will break out of the loop. Not only that, it will shifts the control to the statements after the calling function.

Comment: The problem is with the `return` statement.  When you call `return`, you exit the current function at that moment.  Your loop will only ever run once because of this

Answer (score 0):

Use `loadImage` in `ES6` format: 
change:

```
loadImage(){
        // ...
}
```

to:

```
loadImage = () => {
    // ...
}
```

Then, you have to push  to a array:

```
let arr = [] // empty array
for ( let  i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    // ...
    arr.push(
        <Image
            source={{ uri: this.state.imagesUrl[i] }}
            style={{ styles.Image }} // your styles
         />
    )
}
this.setState(arr)
```

and then in your jsx:

```
render(){
    let {arr} = this.state
    return(
        <View>
            {arr}
        </View>
    )
}
```